# prevent the action happen twice

Tags: jquery

i made a small menu with `<ul>` `<li>`:

**js:**

```
$('#ulAcoesCliente li').click(function(ev) {
    $(".ulNone").each(function(){
        if($(this).css("display") == "block"){
            $(this).hide('slow');
        }
    });
    $(this).find('>ul').toggle('slow');
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

the each get any menu aready opened, close and open where the user click, like a accordeon ( one at a time ).

but if i click in the same, the event will happen twice.

> 1. will close the current sub-menu
> 2. will open again.

how can i prevent that to happen ?

i accept any tips to make this event more better/**intelligent**.

Thansks

edit:

html as required

```
                              <ul id="ulAcoesCliente">
                                    <li>
                                        <button style="font-size: 9px;" id="optComentario">Comentario</button>
                                        <ul class='ulNone' style="display: none;">
                                            <li>
                                                <button style="font-size: 9px; width: 150px;" id="liInserirComentario">Inserir comentario</button>
                                                <ul style="display: none;">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div style="margin-left: 10px;padding: 5px;">
                                                            <input id="comentario" type="text" size="20"/>
                                                            <button style="font-size: 9px; width: 60px;" id="butInsereComent">Salvar</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li style="margin-top: 3px;"><button style="font-size: 9px; width: 150px;" id="listaComent">Listar comentarios</button></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <button style="font-size: 9px; margin-top: 3px;" id="OptEmail">E-mail</button>
                                        <ul class='ulNone' style="display: none;">
                                            <li style="margin-top: 5px;"><button style="font-size: 9px; width: 150px;" id="enviaEmail">Enviar E-mail</button></li>
                                            <li style="margin-top: 3px;"><button style="font-size: 9px; width: 150px;" id="listaEmails">Listar E-mails</button></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <button style="font-size: 9px; margin-top: 3px;" id="">Tarefa</button>
                                        <ul class='ulNone' style="display: none;">
                                            <li style="margin-top: 5px;"><button style="font-size: 9px; width: 150px;" id="">Criar Tarefa</button></li>
                                            <li style="margin-top: 3px;"><button style="font-size: 9px; width: 150px;" id="">Listar Tarefas</button></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
```

**edit 2:**

i reach this: ( **@Jayendra**, did the same )

but the second level, close.

```
     if(!($(this).children('ul').css("display") == "block")){
        $(".ulNone").each(function(){
            if($(this).css("display") == "block"){
                $(this).stop(true,true).hide('slow');
            }
        });
        $(this).find('>ul').stop(true,true).toggle('slow');
        ev.stopPropagation();
    }
```

Comment: Will you please add the HTML as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that this `.ulNone` that you're looping through will select the same `ul` as your `$(this).find('>ul')` selector, causing it to close and then open again.

Since you want the top buttons to drive the toggling you should put the event on that, not the `li`.

```
$('#ulAcoesCliente > li > button').click(function(ev) {
    $(this).next().toggle('slow');
    $(this).parent("li").siblings().find(".ulNone:visible").toggle('slow');
});
```

---

**Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/cnWjg/**

Comment: i need only one menu at a time.

Comment: can u make it done working with second level ?  check @Jayendra post a live demo, the problem are happing there to.

Comment: open the first menu and click in `Inserir Comentario` , will close instead open.

Comment: I'm not seeing that in Chrome. What Browser? You want it to close the top when you click the 2nd level button?

Comment: yes, its not one level menu, click the first menu, then click `Inserir Comentario` , will close, if u open the first menu again, the  level 2 menu will be open.

Answer (score 1):

Try - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/64h9U/)

```
$('#ulAcoesCliente li').click(function(ev) {
    if(!$(this).find('>ul').is(':visible')){
        $(".ulNone:visible").hide('slow');
        $(this).find('>ul').toggle('slow');
        ev.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: works, but check your demo, if u click in the 2 level , he close. i did this few mintus ago. :)

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest doing something like this:

```
$('#ulAcoesCliente li').click(function() {
  $('#ulAcoesCliente li').slideUp();
  $(this).slideDown();
});
```

Comment: You can also replace that slideUp line to do something like you have which is:

`code`
$('#ulAcoesCliente li').each(function() {
 if ($(this).css('display')) == "none") $(this).slideUp();
});
`code`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
// caching
var $ulNone = $('.ulNone').filter(function () {
    return $(this).css('display') === 'block';
});

// handler
$('#ulAcoesCliente > li').click(function (e) {

    e.stopPropagation();

    var $myUl = $(this).find('> ul').show('slow');
    $ulNone.not($myUl).hide('slow');

});
```

The key is removing the `UL` you're clicking on from the set that you're hiding.

Of course, if you're OC about it, you can just throw the `toggle` logic into one statement:

```
$ulNone.not(
    $(this).find('> ul').show('slow')
).hide('slow');
```

Hurts readability a bit though.